# What is the Significance of this "Tab Style"?

Tags: tab

I am having this doubt always whenever I am creating a new Custom Object and selecting a style using "Tab Style Selector" with lots of small thumb nail images and description. Eg:- Airplane, Bank, Castle, Umbrella, Wrench

Whats the exact significance of this? Is it only for just identification or Grouping? Whether the selection of any of the Tab Style will have any Impact on its property or security.

Comment: No impact to security or any metadata properties (other than perhaps adding one to store which icon was selected). Perhaps a psychological one though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tab style does not have any impact on security or access. It's a visual representation which lets you identify a tab easily, especially handy in case you have a lot of tabs. The tab itself may represent a custom object, a VF page, a lightning page or a web tab.

[image]

You can use one of the built-in styles or [use a custom icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/best_practices_admin_icons.htm) to create your own tab style.

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about the custom icon option. Good stuff.